# abkürzen und verkürzen

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen abkürzen und verkürzen (sind sie jemals Synonyme) wenn es um etwas Schriftliches oder eine Veranstaltung (etwas was dauert) geht?

Im Duden gibt es auf der einen Seite:

> eine Rede, ein Verfahren, einen Besuch abkürzen (Duden)

und auf der anderen Seite:

> den Urlaub verkürzen (Duden)

---

Und:

> Ein Wort, einen Namen abkürzen

---

> Eine verkürzte Fassung, Namensform
>
> Eine Rede verkürzt abdrucken

Comment: Nicht als Verb, aber als Adjektiv gibt es den Begriff des *verkürzen Verfahrens*. Ansonsten fällt mir kein Zusammenhang ein, bei dem man die Wahl zwischen beiden Begriffen hätte.

Answer (score 2):

Auch beim DWDS ist z.B. in der Etymologie kein Unterschied zwischen [abkürzen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/abk%C3%BCrzen) und [verkürzen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verk%C3%BCrzen) ersichtlich.

Dennoch sehe ich diesen Verwendungsunterschied:

- abkürzen: ich erreiche das selbe Ziel, der "Aufwand" ist kleiner
- verkürzen: ich erreiche ein ähnliches Ziel mit demselben Kern, der "Aufwand" ist (meist) kleiner

Angewendet auf Beispiele:

- ein Wort abkürzen = aus Bundesrepublik Deutschland wird BRD, ist inhaltlich dasselbe
- den Weg abkürzen / eine Abkürzung nehmen = ich komme immer noch bei A an, doch mein Weg war kürzer
- einen Weg verkürzen = das Zielobjekt ist anders als vorher => es ist immer noch Weg, nur ist das Ziel anders geworden, es mag die gleiche Funktion erfüllen (sonst wäre das verkürzen zwecklos)
- eine Rede abkürzen = den unwichtigen Teil weglassen

  - z.B. aus "Hallo liebe Gäste, ich erzähle Ihnen erst die Schlossgeschichte, dann die Parkgeschichte und dann zeige ich Ihnen das Haus." wäre abgekürzt "Hallo liebe Gäste, ich zeigen Ihnen das Haus(, mehr Zeit ist leider nicht)."
  - => es ist wichtig, beim Abkürzen von Text die Zielinformation zu identifizieren, sie muss für das Abkürzen identisch bleiben, für das Verkürzen nur im Kern:
- eine Rede verkürzt wiedergeben = die Kern-Aussage der Rede bleibt erhalten & (mind.) Details fehlen, die Form schrumpft

  - z.b. statt "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, ich heiße Sie in unserem wunderschönen Hotel aufs allerherzlichste Willkommen!" wäre die verkürzte Version "Hallo und Willkommen im Hotel!"
  - z.B. alle Füllwörter & Nebensätze weglassen
  - d.h. also Text verkürzen geht mit Stiländerung und Informationsverlust einher, z.B. falls im Original etwas ausdifferenziert wurde
- einen Strick verkürzen = ihn z.B. abschneiden => es ist immer noch ein Strick, doch aufgrund geringerer Länge anders zu verwenden

D.h., abkürzen und verkürzen unterscheidet sich vor allem darin, was ich danach habe. Setzt vorraus, dass klar ist, was ich habe.

Comment: Ich kann das nicht nachvollziehen, dass verkürzen ein anderes Ergebnis bedeuten soll. Für mich erschöpft sich der Unterschied in der Konnotation: *abgekürzt* ist neutral bis positiv (ich bin eher da, weil ich einen kürzeren Weg kenne), *verkürzen* neutral bis negativ. Bei einer verkürzten Wiedergabe besteht eben die Gefahr, dass sich Missverständnisse einschleichen oder der Sinn entstellt wird. Dazu passt, dass in der Frage Urlaub eher *verkürzt* als *abgekürzt* wird.

Comment: schließe mich da guidot an, *abkürzen* heißt eher, *etwas **zu langes** vereinfachen oder abbrechen* (die negative Eigenschaft der Länge verringern), *verkürzen* eher *etwas (ungewollt) zu kurz werden zu lassen* (die positive Eigenschaft Länge verringern). Wenn ich z.B. eine Besprechung *abkürze*, dann wäre sie sonst unnötig langatmig gewesen, ohne dass man mehr gelernt hätte. Eine *verkürzte* Besprechung ist hingegen nicht abgeschlossen worden (weil vorzeitig abgebrochen) und lässt Fragen offen. Eine *Abkürzung* entstellt den Sinn nicht, eine *Verkürzung* unterschlägt etwas.

Comment: Ich bedanke mich ganz herzlich für die hilfreichen Kommentare. 

Nur noch eine Frage: wie wäre es mit Büchern oder Filmen - [z.B. Der Film Apocalypse Now erschien zuerst in seiner gekürzte/abgekürzte/verkürzte Fassung.]
 Im Internet bin ich nur auf "gekürzt" gestoßen.

Comment: @Guidot: Beim Versuch die Worte abkürzen u. verkürzen den Kategorien positiv und negativ zuzuordnen am Beispiel einer Rede - wessen Perspektive ist da relevant und wieso, die des Redners, die desjenigen, der sie wiedergibt, die des Hörers/Lesers, die desjenigen, der darüber berichtet oder die seiner Leser/Hörer?  M. E. ist der Term "verkürzt" überhaupt kein Indiz für eine Wertung. Eine solche kann sich immer nur aus dem Kontext ergeben. Ebensowenig ist abkürzen ein wertender Begriff. Die Rede von Konnotationen ist mal wieder verfehlt.

Comment: Shegit Brahm: @Chieron s Kommentar muss ich genauso widersprechen. verkürzen bedeutet nicht etwas zu kurz werden zu lässen. Ich kann eine Fahrradkette kürzen oder verkürzen - diese werden üblicherweise zu lang geliefert, um auf viele Modelle zu passen, man muss sie quasi für jedes Modell einkürzen.

Comment: @userunknown da würde ich immer *kürzen* benutzen, oder das vor dir gebrauchte *einkürzen*. Bei einer *verkürzten* Kette schwingt für mich immer das *zu* Kurze mit, wobei es nicht so eindeutig ist.

Comment: @Chieron: Ich würde zwar zustimmen, dass oft da, wo _verkürzen_ benutzt wird, _kürzen_ besser gewesen wäre, aber im Sprachgebrauch ist verkürzen allgegenwärtig, bis in Zeitungsredaktionen hinein ("X will Stau in der Y-Straße verkürzen") und eben oft nicht abwertend. Wer wäre gegen Stauverkürzung? Deswegen kann man eine negative Konnotation wohl ausschließen.

Comment: @guidot. ich kann bei ver- und abkürzen keinerlei positiv-negativ-Intention erkennen. Urlaub zu verkürzen ist für mich dann ein anderer Urlaub - es ist immer noch Urlaub, doch 14 Tage sind nicht 21 Tage.

Comment: @Chieron. m.E. habe ich genau das geschrieben; abkürzen = gleich, verkürzen = nur im Kern gleich. guidot hingegegen zweifelt an, dass verkürzen das Ergebnis verändert.

Answer (score 1):

Verkürzen wird vor allem in Verbindung mit Zeit genutzt. Verkürze Veranstaltung, verkürzter Film. Dies kann sich dann auch auf die Zeit zur Rezeption eines Inhalts (verkürzter Text) übertragen.

Abkürzen hingegen ist zumeist Räumlich gemeint. Abkürzen eines Weges, etc. Wird ein Wort abgekürzt, was sich ja nur auf die Schrift, nicht aber auf das Lesen bezieht, wird ebenfalls der von den Buchstaben eingenommene Raum verkleinert.

Comment: Das stimmt nur, wenn man immer laut liest, und die Abkürzungen dann ungekürzt vorliest, sei es nun PKW oder F.D.P. Außerdem würde ich sagen, dass man ein Kabel kürzt oder verkürzt, nicht abkürzt.

Comment: @userunknown Meine Formulierung lässt bewusst Ausnahmen zu. Ein Kabel würde ich generell kürzen, also weder ver- noch abkürzen und nur "kürzen" war ja nicht teil der Frage. Sonst fällt mir auch noch "einkürzen" (z.B. einen Zweig einkürzen, beim Gehölzschnitt) sowie "zurückkürzen" (z.B. von finanziellen Mitteln) ein.